# How to make dynamic stub functions on the fly?

Tags: python

I have a class with about 200 stub functions, they look something like this:

```
def name1(self, **kwargs):
    return self.run('name-1', kwargs)

def name2(self, ** kwargs):
    return self.run('name-2', kwargs)
```

So on and so forth.

There is a run function that takes care of the real work.

I want to reduce the 200 stub function to just 1 dynamic function that gets called when you make a call to the class with a method name that doesn't exist.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into `__getattr__`? Is the transformation from method name to run parameter well defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `__getattr__` method in your class that returns a wrapper function around `run`. You just need a way to translate between the method name (e.g. `name1`) and the string that should get passed to the `run` method (e.g. `"name-1"`). It would of course be easiest if there wasn't any change. Here's a quick implementation that uses a dictionary for the translation. If you need it to work for many names you might want to do it with string operations and regex instead.

```
name_translation_dict = {"name1": "name-1", "name2": "name-2"}

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name not in self.name_translation_dict:
        raise AttributeError()
    translated_name = self.name_translation_dict[name]
    def method(**kwargs):
        return self.run(translated_name, kwargs)
    return method
```

Comment: Will this be able to distinguish between member functions and non-function attributes?

Comment: @machineyearning what do you mean by that?

Comment: `__getattr__` only gets called for attributes that can't be found using the regular attribute lookup logic. So other methods and attributes will not trigger it. The `if` check at the start makes sure it only works for names in the translation dictionary.

Comment: What if the programmer tries to access an attribute that doesn't exist, for example a typo on the RHS of an assignment statement? Won't this modification create a function handle every time a non-existent attribute is "accessed"?

Comment: I raise this issue just because his question is specifically about creating member functions dynamically, not other kinds of attributes. The latter is probably undesired functionality which could for example create bugs that are hard to track down.

Comment: @machineyearning yes, it would, but you could have a whitelist or some regex pattern that would match a valid run parameter. Otherwise just raise an `AttributeError` as normal

Comment: @Blckknght Do I need to do a setattr as well?

Comment: and shouldn't this: "return self.run(translated_name, **kwargs)" be this: "return self.run(translated_name, kwargs)"

Comment: @Hec: Ah, if `run` expects to be passed a dictionary, then you're right, and it should be `kwargs` instead of `**kwargs`. You don't need a `__setattr__` unless you want `self.name1 = foo` to do something special (e.g. not just shadow the method named `name1`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more general and potentially more efficient version of @Blckknight's excellent and relatively concise [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901367/355230).

It's longer because it's more general in the sense that it uses a regular expression to translate the name the stub function was called with into the `name` argument to pass the class's `run()` method, and may be more efficient overall since is saves the stub functions it creates on-the-fly, effectively caching them so they don't needed to be re-created if used again. That's because [`__getattr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) is only called when an attribute isn't found in the usual places, but after the first time it will be (in the class's `__dict__`).

```
import re

class MyClass(object):
    _STUB_PREFIX = 'name'
    _STUB_PATTERN = _STUB_PREFIX + r'''(\d+)'''

    def run(self, name, **kwargs):
        print('run({!r}, {})'.format(name, kwargs))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        matches = re.search(self._STUB_PATTERN, name)
        if not matches:
            raise AttributeError(
                "'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
                    self.__class__.__name__, name))
        num = matches.group(1)
        translated_name = '-'.join((self._STUB_PREFIX, num))
        def stub(**kwargs):
            return self.run(translated_name, **kwargs)
        setattr(type(self), name, stub)  # add stub to class
        return stub

obj = MyClass()
obj.name1()  # -> run('name-1', {})
obj.name2()  # -> run('name-2', {})
obj.name1()  # -> run('name-1', {}), but __getattr__(self, 'name1') not called
obj.foo42()  # -> AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'foo42'
```

Comment: Hec: You're welcome. You realize, of course, that needing something this might be an indication of a higher-level issue with a design that requires a class to have 200 methods, stub or otherwise — perhaps that's what you really need to be working on...

Comment: It's a necessity for what we are trying to do.

Comment: I don't get how you are doing the setattr, shouldn't it be "setattr(type(self), name, stub)" ?

Comment: Hec: Yes, my mistake — fixed. I had it that way at one point because I tested whether `__getattr__` was being called a second time, but must have screwed-up some variable renaming I did just before posting. Good catch.